# Powershell modifying HTML from ConvertTo-HTML

Tags: html, regex, powershell-2.0

I have a script that generates an array of objects that I want to email out in HTML format. That part works fine. I am trying to modify the HTML string to make certain rows a different font color.

Part of the html string looks like this (2 rows only):

```
<tr>
    <td>ABL - Branch5206 Daily OD Report</td>
    <td>'\\CTB052\Shared_Files\FIS-BIC Reporting\Report Output Files\ABL\Operations\Daily\ABL - Branch5206 Daily OD Report.pdf'</td>
    <td>13124</td>
    <td>4/23/2013 8:05:34 AM</td>
    <td>29134</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Delivered</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>ABL - Branch5206 Daily OD Report</td>
    <td>'\\CTB052\Shared_Files\FIS-BIC Reporting\Report Output Files\ABL\Operations\Daily\ABL - Branch5206 Daily OD Report.xls'</td>
    <td>15716</td>
    <td>4/23/2013 8:05:34 AM</td>
    <td>29134</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Delivered</td>
</tr>
```

I tried regex to add a font color to the beginning and end of the rows where the row ends with "Delivered":
`$email  = [regex]::Replace($email, "<tr><td>(.*?)Delivered</td></tr>", '<tr><font color = green><td>$1Delivered</td></font></tr>')`

This didn't work (I am not sure if you can set font color for a whole row like that).

Any ideas on how to do this easily/efficiently? I have to do it on several different statuses (like Delivered)

Comment: try `<tr>(((?!</tr>).)*Delivered)` as your RegEx String and `<tr style="color: #FF0000">$1` as your replacement string.  If it works, I'll submit it as an answer and explain why.  Unfortunately, I don't know PowerShell so I'm reaching.

Comment: That makes the whole table red, not just the row.

Comment: I decided just to break it up using each status as a separate table (used Where-object). I think this makes more sense and I don't want to spend a ton of time on formatting. I could change the color more easily this way, but decided it probably wasn't necessary since the headings really set off each status.

Comment: I found that doing that, I could use the -precontent paramater and put in formatting for each section.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: HTML **cannot** be parsed by regular expression parser. A regular expression will NOT provide a general solution to this problem. If your HTML structure is well known and you don't have any other `<tr></tr>` elements, though, the following might work. On that note, though, is there some reason you can't modify the HTML generation to do this then instead of waiting until the HTML is already generated?

Try this command:

```
PS > $email = $email -replace '(?s)<tr>(.*?)<td>Delivered</td>(.*?)</tr>','<tr style="color: #FF0000">$1<td>Delivered</td>$2</tr>'
```

The first string is the pattern. The `(?s)` tells the parser to allow `.` to accept newlines; this is called "single line" mode. Then it grabs a `<tr>` element that contains the string `<td>Delivered</td>`. The two capture groups grab everything else in the `<tr>` element around the `<td>Delivered</td>` string. Take note of the question marks following the `*`s. `*` by itself is greedy and matches as much text as possible; `*?` matches as little text as possible. If we just used `*` here, it would treat your entire string as one match and only replace the first `<tr>`.

The second string is the replacement. It plops the `<tr>` element and its contents back in place with an added style attribute, and all without back ref.

One other minor note is the quoting. I tend toward single quotes anyway, but in this case, you're likely to have double quotes in the replacement string. So single quotes are probably the way to go.

As for how you could do this for different statuses, regular expressions really aren't designed for conditional content like that; it's like trying to use a screwdriver as a drill. You can hard code several replaces or loop over status/color pairs and build your pattern and replace strings from them. A full blown HTML parser would be more efficient if you can find one for .NET; you might try to get away with an XML parser if you can guarantee it's valid XML. Or, going back to my question at the beginning, you could modify the HTML generation. If your e-mails are few in number, though, this may not be a bottleneck worth addressing. Development time spent is also costly. See if it's fast enough and try a different route if not.

Credit where it's due: I took the HTML style attribute from @FrankieTheKneeMan.

Comment: I made the color green but used your code. It made the header row green, most, but not all of the delivered rows green, and some other statuses green too. I think this can work, i is just getting the right html in the right places. I no little about html, which is part of the problem. I had it working for just changing the color of "delivered".

Comment: As to pre-processing, I don't know html well, so I am trying to avoid rolling my own from scratch.  I also tried putting code in the actual powershell object properties, but the ConvertHTML messed those up. I tried in the first field prefixing with color style and the last field suffixing with color style.

Comment: You haven't told us how your data is structured or how you're transforming it to HTML. Where is the `ConvertHTML` function from? Can you point to some documentation on it?

Comment: @user1921849 Also, I'm curious about what rows failed the replace.